# How did confederate banks deal with loan defaults?

Tags: american-civil-war

Okay, so I know that when the confederacy was established, they printed new money and gave out bonds in that money. My question is, if you were to take out a house loan in confederate money at the beginning of the war, how would you pay off the loan once the confederacy fell?  Would the bank have to just default on the loan as it was issued in a currency that is no longer valid?

Comment: Which bank? Which loan? Which year? Which State? There is no possibility of a definitive answer with so many variables.

Comment: hmm, alright ill refine my question some.

Comment: In this case, it's not the bank that is at risk of default, it's the borrower - they're the one repaying the loan. The bank presumably made the loan with some some form of security in place (usually a lein on the property). If the borrower fails to repay the loan, the bank would seize the property. Logic suggests that some form of conversion/exchange rate was in place to allow people to repay loans in US currency.

Comment: @KillingTime: The standard at the time would likely have been to denominate the loan in either gold or silver. Note also that with its declaration of secession from the U.S.A. the Confederacy transformed itself from one of the wealthiest societies in the World, into one of the poorest. Plantations worth millions a few weeks earlier could now barely command the interest on a wooden nickel - because the income stream underlying the value had disappeared.